# Prove that $\frac{2^{x+1}+(x+1)^2}{2^x+x^2}\rightarrow 2$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: convergence-divergence

Could someone please show me the proof that $\frac{2^{x+1}+(x+1)^2}{2^x+x^2}\rightarrow 2$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

I have no idea where to begin with this one.

Thanks.

Comment: How about dividing top and bottom by $2^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2^{x+1}+(x+1)^2}{2^x+x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2\cdot 2^{x}+x^2+2x+1}{2^x+x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(2^{x}+x^2)+(2^x+2x+1)}{2^x+x^2}$$
$$=1+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2^x+2x+1}{2^x+x^2}$$
Using L-Hospital's rule 3 times:
$$=1+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2^x\ln 2+2}{2^x\ln 2+2x}$$
$$=1+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2^x(\ln 2)^2}{2^x(\ln 2)^2+2}$$
$$=1+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2^x(\ln 2)^3}{2^x(\ln 2)^3}$$
$$=1+\lim_{x\to \infty}1=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 3):

Divide numerator and denominator by $2^n$. It's not hard to show that $\frac{x^2}{2^n}\to 0$ (use L'Hôpital's rule, for example) to see $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{x+1}+(x+1)^2}{2^x+x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2+(x+1)^2/2^x}{1+x^2/2^x}=2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2\cdot (2^{x}+x^2)+(x+1)^2-2x^2}{2^x+x^2}$$
$$=2+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(x+1)^2-2x^2}{2^x+x^2}$$

($\frac{\infty}{\infty}$)form so using L-Hospital's rule twice:
$$=2+\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-2}{2^x (ln2)^2+2}$$
$$=2$$